# Read last 50 bytes python

Tags: python

I wanted to read last 50 bytes from a file.

I've used the following code to read first 50 bytes.

```
def read_file(filepath):
    open_file = open(filepath)
    return "".join("{:02x}".format(int(ord(c))) for c in open_file.read(50))
```

Comment: Read this: [How to read the last MB of a very large text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19046369/how-to-read-the-last-mb-of-a-very-large-text-file)

Comment: It reads by line, not in bytes

Comment: @jOSe The first answer on the duplicate post does not read by line.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying out the code....!

Comment: How to return the data, as I mentioned in my question ?