# How to print the last byte of a file .txt

Tags: python, file, byte

**python**

I have a text file (.txt) and I need to print to the last byte of the txt.
how I do that ?
When I do not know the size of the document.

Comment: Similar: [How to read the last MB of a very large text file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19046369)

Answer (score 1):

The [documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) provides an API, that can be used to solve that problem. You will need to do the following things in order:

1. Open the file in text mode like in the example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o).
2. Change the file pointer to the last byte. This can be achieved using the [`seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) memeber function of the file object. Use the `SEEK_END` token with an offset of `-1` to get one byte before the end of the file
3. Read one byte with the [`read`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read) function.
4. Print that byte.
5. If you did not use a context manager (`with` keyword) while opening the file, you should use [`close`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.close) to close the file before exiting the program

The trick here is to use the `seek` method, that can be used to specify an offset relative to the end of the file.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```py
with open("text.txt") as file:
    text = outfile.read()
    byte_array = bytearray(text, "utf8")

    print(byte_array[-1:])
```

If you need the binary representation

```py
with open("text.txt") as file:
    text = outfile.read()
    byte_array = bytearray(text, "utf8")

    binary_byte_list = []

    for byte in byte_array:
        binary_representation = bin(byte)
        binary_byte_list.append(binary_representation)

    print(binary_byte_list[-1:])
```

Comment: Good answer. Note that this loads the entire file into memory. For small and medium sized files this will not be a problem though. Also note that you have not to convert all the bytes to binary representation, if you just want to print the last one. Instead of the last 4 lines you could just write `print(bin(byte_array[-1]))` or `print(hex(byte_array[-1]))` for hexadecimal representation.

Comment: @JakobStark good points. Did not care about the optimizing I must say, but you are totally right.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this using seek which obviates the need to read the entire file into memory:

```
import os
with open('foo.txt', 'rb') as foo:
    foo.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
    b = foo.read()
    print(b)
```

In this case the last character is newline and therefore:

**Output:**

```
b'\n'
```

**Note:**

File opened in binary mode